# Instruct GCC to link as C++

Tags: c++, gcc, linker

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linking C++ code with 'gcc' (without g++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001535/linking-c-code-with-gcc-without-g)

GCC provides the `-x lang` option, which allows you to modify the assumed language during compilation. What is the equivalent for the link step? I wish to link a program that has C++ dependencies via the `gcc` command.

Answer (score 3):

You need to link against libstdc++ by passing `-lstdc++`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `-lstdc++` flag should do the job.

Comment: Who answered with `-lstdc++` first?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the g++ frontend instead. (automake also does that as you will see - it calls CXXLD instead of CCLD when one of the source files is .cpp.)
[Just using gcc with -lstdc++ won't help, because the gcc and g++ frontends can use different linker commands. On mine, gcc adds --as-needed when calling the linker, while g++ doesn't.]