# How do I compile and link C++ code with compiled C code?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, undefined-symbol, cmockery

I want to be able to use [Cmockery](http://code.google.com/p/cmockery/) to mock C functions called from C++ code I'm testing.  As a step towards that, I've renamed the Cmockery example [run_tests.c](http://code.google.com/p/cmockery/source/browse/trunk/src/example/run_tests.c?r=42) to run_tests.cpp, and am attempting to compile and link it with cmockery.c:

```
g++ -m32 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DPIC -I ../cmockery-0.1.2 -I /usr/include/malloc -c run_tests.cpp -o obj/run_tests.o
gcc -m32 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DPIC -Wno-format -I ../cmockery-0.1.2 -I /usr/include/malloc -c ../cmockery-0.1.2/cmockery.c -o obj/cmockery.o
g++  -m32 -o run_tests obj/run_tests.o obj/cmockery.o
```

The first two command lines (to compile) are successful, but after the last I get:

```
Undefined symbols:
  "_run_tests(UnitTest const*, unsigned long)", referenced from:
      _main in run_tests.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

That undefined symbol is from line 29 of run_tests.cpp:

```
return run_tests(tests);
```

The run_tests() function is defined in cmockery.c.

After reading "[Linking C++ code with 'gcc' (without g++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001535/linking-c-code-with-gcc-without-g)", I tried:

```
gcc -lstdc++ -m32 -o run_tests obj/run_tests.o obj/cmockery.o
```

But got the same result:

```
Undefined symbols:
  "_run_tests(UnitTest const*, unsigned long)", referenced from:
      _main in run_tests.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How do I compile and link C++ code so it finds the symbols in C code?

Comment: None of the answers (at the time of writing this comment) make it clear that I don't need to modify cmockery.h.  I can put the `extern "C"` declaration around the `#include <cmockery.h>` in run_tests.cpp.  I'll accept the first answer to make this clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that you can get thinkgs to link from C++ by adding the following around the contents of the cmockery.h file:

At or near the beginning:

```
#if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C" {
#endif
```

At or near the end:

```
#if defined(__cplusplus)
}
#endif
```

That way, use of the header in C sources will ignore the `extern "C"` part of the declaration, but when the header is include in C++ builds, the compiler will be properly told that the linkage for the declarations in that header use C semantics.

For a quick-n-dirty test or if you'd rather not modify the header, you can try:

```
extern "C" {
#include "cmockery.h"
}
```

but my preference would be to put the `extern "C"` block in the header (and only around the stuff that's required - that might need a bit of analysis).

Comment: Why do you consider putting the `extern "C"` around the `#include` "quick-n-dirty"?

Comment: In the general case because it might apply the `extern "C"` modifier to stuff that doesn't expect it (in particular if the header includes other headers that are C++ aware). Headers could handle this by using the `extern "C++"` declaration spec, but I've only seen that used once to handle this case (probably because it's little known, and it's not needed nearly as much as the `extern "C"` version).

Answer (score 5):

In your header files included by your C++ code, you need `extern "C"` declarations for all the functions that are compiled in C.

Answer (score 2):

when you include the C header files from C++, have you wrapped the prototypes with `extern "C" { .... }`? If you don't the C++ function name wil be 'mangled' at link time.

Answer (score 2):

As Karl said, `extern "C" { .. }` is needed.

The reason: C++ mangles the names (adds funny characters) so that linking is type safe. C doesn't, so in that language linking `foo(int)` to `foo(double)` is possible (but wrong and embarrassing).

For successful interoperability, you need to tell the C++ compiler that some function names are not to be mangled, in order for linking to succeed.