# How to combine a C++ object file in a C project compiled with gcc (not g++)?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++

Yet another C/C++ integration question: I am trying to update some legacy C library (let's call it `libcl.a`) with functionality that I have in a C++ library (let's call it `libcppl.a`). The `liblc.a` library is being used all over in my environment and is linked into many C projects, using GCC (in the C compiler mode):

```
>> gcc prog.c -lcl
```

The `libcl.a` currently consists of the `cl.o` object file (created with `gcc` from `cl.c`+`cl.h`).

The `libcppl.a` consists of the `cppl.o` object file (created with `g++` from `cppl.cpp`+`cppl.h`).

Because the existing applications are written in C, and the build scripts are using GCC, I'd like to keep the transition to the updated library as simple as possible. Thus, I want to keep using GCC as the main compiler but still be able to link with the updated library.

Finding [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1001576/274579), I could link C++ objects into GCC C project using `-lstdc++`:

```
>> gcc -c cl.c   -o cl.o
>> g++ -c cppl.c -o cppl.o
>> ar rcs libcl.a cl.o cppl.o
>> gcc prog.c -lcl -lstdc++
```

However, I want to **eliminate the explicit mention of the** `libstdc++` **in the compile command line**.

What I tried to do was to include libstdc++ in the cl library, by doing:

```
>> ar rcs libcl.a cl.o cppl.o /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
```

However, when building the application, I get:

```
>> gcc prog.c -lcl
In file included from cppl.cpp:2:
./libcl.a(cppl.o):(.eh_frame+0x12): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**1. Why doesn't the gcc linker find the C++ standard library that was archived together with my objects?**

**2. Is there a limitation on using** `ar` **with libraries (as opposed to object files)?**

**3. Is there a way to overcome this problem?**

Comment: Why do you want to remove `libstdc++` from the command line?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas - because I already have build scripts that I don't want to change.

Comment: If it is that costly to change your build scripts, your main issue is not the question, but how to fix your build system. Programming is among other things adapting to a changing environment, and this should be a simple change in the build script. Solve the underlying issue and the symptom will go away.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas - yes, it may be that costly. It is not just my scripts, but others too, who rely on that library. I'd prefer to try and port the new functionality to C before forcing the general public to use C++ compiler. Otherwise, you are right, as is Michael.

Answer (score 7):

You can separately compile `prog.c` using `gcc`, then use `g++` to link:

```
# compile the main program to an object file
gcc  prog.c -o prog.o

#use g++ to link everything (it'll automatically pull in libstdc++)
g++ prog.o -lcl
```

Alternatively, you can compile and link `prog.c` in one step by explicitly telling `g++` to compile `prog.c` as a C source file using the `-x` option:

```
g++ -x c prog.c -lcl
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5854712/12711 for more information on the difference in behavior between `gcc` and `g++`.

Comment: Thanks, but as I wrote in the question, I want to use GCC and not G++ for building the projects.

Comment: @ysap: hmm - I didn't see that, just the desire to avoid calling out `libstdc++` explicitly.  Even so, I think it would be better to use `g++` or link in `libstdc++` explicitly than to attempt a hack like putting `libstdc++` into another archive (even if you can get it to work). I think that people maintaining the build down the road will not appreciate something oddball like that very much.

Comment: +1, Agree with Michael, it is easier to integrate C in a C++ project than the other way around. The simplest thing is to switch to C++ and then compile specific parts (even if they are 90% of the code) with the C compiler.

Comment: Michael, @DavidRodríguez-dribeas, generally, you are correct and I'd do that. However, there are reasons why I want to keep the "pure C environment". Unfortunately, this answer, and the comments, do not answer any of my 3 questions.

Comment: @ysap: hopefully someone else will be able to answer your questions.