# arm-none-eabi-gcc using C++ code in C: undefined references

Tags: c++, c, embedded, toolchain

i need to use some C++ code in my C program which has to be cross-compiled with the arm-none-eabi toolchain. I am trying the following simple program first:

#### main.c

```
#include "misc.h"

int main(){
    say_hello();
    return 0;
}
```

#### misc.h

```
#ifndef _MISC_H_
#define _MISC_H_

/**
 * \brief Prints hello to stdout
 */
void say_hello();

#endif /* _MISC_H_ */
```

#### misc.c

```
/* C++ implementation */
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void cpp_say_hello(){
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
}

/* C wrapper */
extern "C"{
    #include "misc.h"

    void say_hello(){
        cpp_say_hello();
    }
}
```

#### Makefile

```
CFLAGS += -lstdc++
CXXFLAGS += -c

hello_world_mix: misc.o main.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@

misc.o: misc.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $^ -o $@

clean:
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f *~
```

When i compile it natively (by simply doing 'make') it works just fine. But if i try to cross-compile it with:

```
CC=arm-none-eabi-gcc CXX=arm-none-eabi-g++ CFLAGS=--specs=nosys.specs make
```

This is the undefined references i obtain:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc --specs=nosys.specs -lstdc++ misc.o main.c -o hello_world_mix
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/8.2.0/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: misc.o: in function `cpp_say_hello()':
misc.cpp:(.text+0x34): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/8.2.0/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: misc.cpp:(.text+0x44): undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/8.2.0/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: misc.cpp:(.text+0x5c): undefined reference to `std::cout'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/8.2.0/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: misc.cpp:(.text+0x60): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/8.2.0/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: misc.o: in function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
misc.cpp:(.text+0xb4): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/8.2.0/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: misc.cpp:(.text+0xe4): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:5: hello_world_mix] Error 1
```

What am i missing here?

Comment: Order of libraries *matter*. If source or object file `A` depends on library `B`, then you must link with `A` *first*. Or make it easier for yourself and use `g++` for the linking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're linking with `CC`, you must link with `CXX` - it is not only the  Also you shouldn't add per-line arguments to the `CFLAGS`, `CXXFLAGS`.

```
hello_world_mix: misc.o main.o
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@

main.o: main.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@

misc.o: misc.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $^ -o $@

clean:
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f *~
```

---

The reason might very well be that the ordering of `-l` options might be significant in [*some* GCC versions and not in others.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001535/linking-c-code-with-gcc-without-g) - but it is easier to let g++ worry  about that.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Sorry but if i have to link with g++ shouldn't the make file be like this: https://pastebin.com/raw/X4HgVhQG ?

Comment: @wellsaid oops, fixed.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Now its working for native but for arm-none-eabi i obtain other undefined references: https://pastebin.com/raw/3iRCg5ZA. But maybe this is unrelated to the question

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if your libstdc++ is in sync with the headers!

Comment: I've managed to remote those undefined reference too with this command: make CC=arm-none-eabi-gcc CXX=arm-none-eabi-g++ CXXFLAGS="-specs=nosys.specs -mcpu=cortex-m3"